# Java DataStructures question boxing/unboxing

Tags: java, data-structures, boxing, unboxing

I am studying for a data structures exam tommorrow and need to know what lines in the following code are correct and which aren't and why

```
Object  obj = new Integer(42);
Integer iObj = 43;
iObj = obj;
```

Comment: What do *you* think the answer is, and why? You are the one who is taking the exam, there is little point in just telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your  question is here under:

```
 Object  obj = new Integer(42); //auto boxing  // true
 Integer iObj = 43; //direct intialization   //true
 iObj = obj  // false
 iObj = (Integer) obj; // manual boxing
```

`iObj = obj  is false` because `obj` is a reference to the `Object` and `iObj` is of `Interger`. `Object` is the parent of all and so Integer type `iObj` is child of `obj` and hence false.

```
 In short, child can be auto- boxed to parent but the vice-versa is not possible
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HelloWorld.java:19: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
        iObj = obj;
               ^
1 error
```

The above fails because the compile time type of iObj and obj are not matching.  This is a signature of strongly typed languages.  Similar code in Javascript would work fine.

Comment: Ok I thought that line wouldn't work. So for it to work you would have to typecast it, something like this?
iObj = (int)obj;

Answer (score 0):

All this lines are correct 
 First you crwate object and tgen you create the integer and assing the value to that integer object 
 This lines of code is totally correct

Comment: the last line won't compile in Java actually